# pipe returning null on file open using c code in android ndk

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, pipe

I'm trying to write some native code to my android app that uses 2 file pipes to communicate between the java code and the native code.  The eventual aim is for the native code to communicate over the network and the java code just to listen to both ends of the pipe for both incomng and outgoing data.  This is the code i call from the java app:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_fdtest_Bindings_openSession(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
{
int inpipe[2];
int outpipe[2];
FILE *in;
FILE *out;
if(pipe (inpipe)) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "Unable to set up input pipe");
    return;
}
if(pipe (outpipe)) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "Unable to set up output pipe");
    return;
}
in = fdopen(inpipe[0], "w");
out = fdopen(outpipe[1], "r");
if(in == NULL) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "input pipe null");

}
if(out == NULL) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "output pipe null");

}
}
```

From this I get the output:

```
06-04 09:44:41.759: D/dalvikvm(1443): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.fdtest/lib/libfdtest.so 0x414955a8
06-04 09:44:41.789: D/dalvikvm(1443): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.fdtest/lib/libfdtest.so 0x414955a8
06-04 09:44:41.789: D/NDK_BINDINGS(1443): input pipe null
06-04 09:44:41.799: D/NDK_BINDINGS(1443): output pipe null
```

This seems wierd.  It seems to set up the pipe ok, but then fail on opening the files.  Is this something fundementally wrong with this code, as the documentation seem to suggest this would work.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the man page:

```
pipefd[0] refers to the read end of the pipe.  pipefd[1] refers to the
write end of the pipe.
```

You're trying to open the read end of `inpipe` for writing, and the write end of `outpipe` for reading.  If you print `errno` you'll likely see EACCES.